# How to SUMIFS text beginning with apostrophe

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am receiving a list of products from an external data source. One of the product names begins with an apostrophe. When I attempt to produce a summary of the products and total quantity using `UNIQUE()` and `SUMIFS()` the formula is returning zero for the product that begins with an apostrophe.

I have made an example sheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191bqjUPPPtt5ZKeTw7pUplsve-tBdDBhpBV0Ic3e-nA/edit?usp=sharing

Interestingly, a `VLOOKUP` will work fine, but that will miss additional entries in the list.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this without removing the leading apostrophe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a "fix" with **`SUBSTITUTE`** fx:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(B:B, SUBSTITUTE(A:A, "'", ""), SUBSTITUTE(D2, "'", "")))
```

[image: 0]

Or use **`QUERY`** and have it all in one go:

```
=QUERY(A1:B, "select A,sum(B) where A !='' group by A label sum(B)'Qty'", 1)
```

[image: 0]